# How to display an entire database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html, sqlite

I'm currently using SQlite, writing an application with TideSDK. All I'm after is to display an entire database (all tables) to a user, as it's an assessment tool a teacher needs to view. I'm using HTML5 and Javascript.

I was thinking of putting the entire database into a string or array like:

```
var database = db.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name");
```

Then some how render on screen using javascript/html.

Is this at all possible? Is there a plugin for this kind of stuff? It's been bugging me for weeks and I can't seem to get any help.

Thanks you to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

To list the tables, you should be able to do

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master 
    WHERE type IN ('table','view') 
    ORDER BY 1
```

Or use the shorter version

```
.tables
```

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html.  Go down to Querying the database schema

Comment: thank you for that advice on how to proper get all the tables, but is there any way I can now display them? Can I put them in array and print that to screen? thanks again